# Combine wp_get_attachemnt_image with jQuery to add class before the image is being outputted?

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting images using wp_get_attachemnt_image and then I am using jQuery to check if it is portrait or landscape orientation to add a respective class... This kind of works but not well, sometimes it doesn't work on some images.

Is there a way to add the class after the image is called but before it is outputted?

I am using this code to get the images:

```
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
'order'=>'ASC', 
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
);
$images = get_posts( $args );
foreach($images as $image):
echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'large');
endforeach;
?>
```

and this code to add the classes:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#journal img').each(function(){
$(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' :  'portrait');
});
});
</script>
```

I have also tried echoing the script before the echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'large'); but that does not seem to make a difference. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might initially generate your HTML code with each involved image having class (or direct `style`) for `display: none;`.

Then change your your JS part to show images just when the required class has been set:

```
$(this).addClass(this.width > this.height ? 'landscape' :  'portrait').show();
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a pretty good solution and what I am currently doing now, but I don't like the way the text below the images appears first this way... I guess I can run a script to load the text after the images, but I thought if it was easy to load the images with the class initially that might be the cleanest solution

Comment: @JackCash You might otherwise have containers for each couple image/text, and apply the `display: none` then `show()` to that container instead of image itself.